# QEMU multiple port forwarding

Tags: kvm-virtualization, port-forwarding, qemu

I would like to forward more than one port.

This command run my VM and forwards RDP port successfully:

```
qemu-system-i386 -net nic,model=rtl8139 -net user,hostfwd=tcp::3389-:3389 -m 512M -localtime -cpu core2duo,+nx -smp 2 -usbdevice tablet -k en-us -hda win.img -nographic
```

Tried other commands, but with no luck, all of them seems bad:

```
qemu-system-i386 -net nic,model=rtl8139 -m 512M -localtime -cpu core2duo,+nx -smp 2 -usbdevice tablet -k en-us -hda win.img -nographic -redir tcp:443::443,tcp:992::992,tcp:1194::1194,tcp:5555::5555,udp:1194::1194,udp:500::500,udp:4500::4500,tcp:3389::3389

qemu-system-i386 -net nic,model=rtl8139 -net user,hostfwd=tcp::3389-:3389,tcp:443::443,tcp:992::992,tcp:1194::1194,tcp:5555::5555,udp:1194::1194,udp:500::500,udp:4500::4500 -m 512M -localtime -cpu core2duo,+nx -smp 2 -usbdevice tablet -k en-us -hda win.img -nographic
```

The proper example would be very welcomed. Thank you.

Answer (score 21):

Got it to work:

with `-net`:

```
qemu-system-i386 -net nic,model=rtl8139 \
  -net user,hostfwd=tcp::3389-:3389,hostfwd=tcp::443-:443,hostfwd=tcp::992-:992 \
  -m 512M -localtime -cpu core2duo,+nx -smp 2 -usbdevice tablet \
  -k en-us -hda win.img -nographic
```

Original answer: `redir` (legacy)

```
qemu-system-i386 -net nic,model=rtl8139 \
  -net user,hostfwd=tcp::3389-:3389 \
  -redir tcp:443::443 -redir tcp:992::992 \
  -redir tcp:5555::5555 -redir udp:1194::1194 -redir udp:500::500 \
  -redir udp:4500::4500 \
  -m 512M -localtime -cpu core2duo,+nx -smp 2 -usbdevice tablet \
  -k en-us -hda win.img -nographic
```

Comment: Note that -redir is a legacy option.  To get the same thing working with hostfwd try: `-net user,hostfwd=tcp::3389-:3389,hostfwd=tcp::443-:443,hostfwd=tcp::992-:992,etc...`.  Also I can only get this working when forwarding to the main interface in the guest ( 10.0.2.15 ).

Comment: @joao-costa you can get other interfaces forwarded by selecting the iface, like so
```
-netdev user,id=net0,hostfwd=tcp::5556-:22
```
above from https://wiki.qemu.org/Documentation/Networking#How_to_get_SSH_access_to_a_guest